# Cannot Read Property Split of Undefined for text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I am trying to build a text to morse code translator, and when trying to take the input value which is a string and turn it into an array of letters, I get this error.

```js
var inputValue = getInputValue();
var inputValueLetters = inputValue.split();
function getInputValue(){
    // Selecting the input element and get its value 
    var inputVal = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
    
    // Displaying the value
    console.log(inputVal);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get Text Input Field Value in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Morsi: Translate Plain Text Into Morse Code</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
    
<script src="morsi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called function "getInputValue" at first line of your script.

```
var inputValue = getInputValue();
```

This function return `undefined`, and then you are trying to call `.split` method of undefined and got that error.

If you remove first two lines of your script - you will got no error. 
If you need some additional logic, and not just print input value to console, then you need to place this logic in function `getInputValue`  after reading value of input. Like:

```
function getInputValue(){
  // Selecting the input element and get its value 
  var inputVal = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;

  // Displaying the value
  console.log(inputVal);
  const letters = inputVal.split('');
  console.log(letters);
};
```

Also, check that i used  empty string argument in  split function to split value by letters. If you don't do it you will have array with only one element,that is whole input value

Comment: So what would I use to manipulate the result outside of the function, because inputVal and letters are not defined outside?

Comment: If you  need to share some variables  for different  getInputValue calls or share result with other functions, then you need to move variable to the outer scope ( in global scope in this situation), You can have variable outside, and write value to it in function like. And in function store variables, that you don't need outside.Like

Comment: let letters; /*without any value before first assign;*/

function getInputValue(){
  /*have value in  inputVal  only in this function, and it will be different for each call*/
  const inputVal = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;

  /* we don't have any of var,let,const special words, so we use outer variable*/
  letters = inputVal.split('');
};

function doAnother(){
  /*can have internal variable*/
  const a= 3;
 
  /*can access external variable*/
  if(letters && letters.length){
    console.log(letters.length === a)
  }
};

Comment: @Garberchov 
You can read more by request "scopes in javascript"

Answer (score 1):

This line :

```
var inputValue = getInputValue();
```

Is assigning whatever the function `getInputValue();` return to the variable `inputValue`

That function is return `undefined` which is basically nothing, because there's no `return` statement inside it, So the second line becomes like this:

```
var inputValueLetters = undefined.split();
```

The error you get `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"` is clear enough `undefined` is `nothing` and `nothing` has `nothing` so how can you expect `nothing` to have `split()`.

---

What you want is only when the button is clicked get the value of the input then call `split()` on that value.

Also if you want to split the text into an array of letters you need to tell the split function by which char it want it to split a `space` or a `forward slash (/)` etc..

In our case it's nothing so we pass an empty string `""`

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value 
  var inputValue = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
  var inputValueLetters = inputValue.split("");
  // Displaying the value
  console.log(inputValueLetters);
};
```

```html
<h1>Morsi: Translate Plain Text Into Morse Code</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput" value="text">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.split('')`

```js
const hello = 'hello'
console.log(hello.split())
console.log(hello.split(''))
```